# Twig `Variable does not exist` error despite it not being printed

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to handle non existing variables in my controller which if the database is empty will return a view without any variables:

```
if(!$votes->findOneById(1) || !$images->findOneById(1)){
    return $this->render('admin/stats_and_images.html.twig');
}

return $this->render('admin/stats_and_images.html.twig', [
    'images' => $images->countVotesForAllImages(),
    'image_podium' => $images->getTopNImages(3),
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'votesToday' => $votes->votesToday(),
    'votesMonth' => $votes->votesMonth(),
    'votesTotal' => $votes->votesTotal()
]);
```

And in my view I'm trying to handle the lack of variables like so:

```
        {% if (votesTotal[0][1] is defined) and (votesToday[0][1] is defined) and (votesMonth[0][1] is defined) %}

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4 class="sub-section--header">Liczba Oddanych Głosów:</h4>
                <hr>
                <p>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    Dzisiaj:
                    <span class="text-info large-num">{{ votesToday[0][1] }}</span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    Ten miesiąc:
                    <span class="text-info large-num">{{ votesMonth[0][1] }}</span>
                </div>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Głosów ogółem: </strong><span class="text-info large-num">{{ votesTotal[0][1] }}</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4 class="sub-section--header">Wygrywające zdjęcia:</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Ten miesiąc</p>
                <hr>
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a 
                            href="{{ asset("uploads/"~image_podium[0][0].fileName) }}" 
                            target="blank">
                            <img 
                                src="{{ asset("uploads/"~image_podium[0][0].fileName) | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" alt="{{image_podium[0][0].title}}" 
                                class="site-thumbnail" 
                                title="{{image_podium[0][0].title}} - {{image_podium[0][0].author}}">
                        </a>
                        <p><strong>Głosów: {{image_podium[0]['votes']}}</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a 
                            href="{{ asset("uploads/"~image_podium[1][0].fileName) }}" 
                            target="blank">
                            <img 
                                src="{{ asset("uploads/"~image_podium[1][0].fileName) | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" alt="{{image_podium[1][0].title}}" 
                                class="site-thumbnail" 
                                title="{{image_podium[1][0].title}} - {{image_podium[1][0].author}}">
                        </a>
                        <p>Głosów: {{image_podium[1]['votes']}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a 
                            href="{{ asset("uploads/"~image_podium[2][0].fileName) }}" 
                            target="blank">
                            <img 
                                src="{{ asset("uploads/"~image_podium[2][0].fileName) | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" alt="{{image_podium[2][0].title}}" 
                                class="site-thumbnail"
                                title="{{image_podium[2][0].title}} - {{image_podium[2][0].author}}">
                        </a>
                        <p>Głosów: {{image_podium[2]['votes']}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <h2 class="text-danger text-center">
                No votes at the moment :)
            </h2>
        {% endif %}
```

But still despite the strict requirement of all three fields to be defined I'm getting this:

> Variable "votesToday" does not exist.

And pointing to the `<span class="text-info large-num">{{ votesToday[0][1] }}</span>` portion of the view.

Why would this be happening? How can it be avoided?

Comment: Can add a `{{ dump(votesToday) }}` in your Twig file and edit your post to show what that dumps? Has to be done using the `app_dev.php` URL.

Comment: Make sure you aren't using a cached version of your template. Your [code](https://twigfiddle.com/bt168s) works as is. (Just removed assest function and imagine fitler)

Comment: well if "votesToday" does not exitst you propably have a typo or special character or sth like that, maybe it may work if you copy it back from here ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send $votes to twig and check it with {{ dump(votes) }}

If it is a doctrine entity, check your getter. Perhaps is $votes->getVotesToday()